# install lightfm on windows

Tags: python, windows, failed-installation

I have been trying for days now to achieve this. So please any suggestion is accepted. I tried to install lightfm on my windows but i keep grtting this error

```
Collecting lightfm
  Using cached lightfm-1.12.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from light
fm)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (fr
om lightfm)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from li
ghtfm)
Building wheels for collected packages: lightfm
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lightfm ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, t
okenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-gao0_4o3\\lightfm\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open'
, open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:
\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvva8cxrepip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  Compiling without OpenMP support.
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lightfm
  copying lightfm\evaluation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lightfm
  copying lightfm\lightfm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lightfm
  copying lightfm\_lightfm_fast.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lightfm
  copying lightfm\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lightfm
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lightfm\datasets
  copying lightfm\datasets\movielens.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lightfm\datasets
  copying lightfm\datasets\stackexchange.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lightfm\datasets
  copying lightfm\datasets\_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lightfm\datasets
  copying lightfm\datasets\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lightfm\datasets
  copying lightfm\_lightfm_fast_no_openmp.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lightfm
  copying lightfm\_lightfm_fast_openmp.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lightfm
  running build_ext
  building 'lightfm._lightfm_fast_no_openmp' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\lightfm
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\u
sers\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include -Ic:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include "-IC
:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10
240.0\ucrt" /Tclightfm/_lightfm_fast_no_openmp.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\lightfm/_lightfm_fast_no_openmp.obj
 -ffast-math -march=native
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ffast-math'
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-march=native'
  _lightfm_fast_no_openmp.c
  c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include\pyconfig.h(243): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include fil
e: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit st
atus 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lightfm
  Running setup.py clean for lightfm
  Complete output from command c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, t
okenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-gao0_4o3\\lightfm\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open'
, open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  Compiling without OpenMP support.
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: option --all not recognized

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for lightfm
Failed to build lightfm
Installing collected packages: lightfm
  Running setup.py install for lightfm ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
 tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-gao0_4o3\\lightfm\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'ope
n', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --recor
d C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-eybv98gb-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Compiling without OpenMP support.
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'lightfm._lightfm_fast_no_openmp' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:
\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include -Ic:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include "-
IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.
10240.0\ucrt" /Tclightfm/_lightfm_fast_no_openmp.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\lightfm/_lightfm_fast_no_openmp.o
bj -ffast-math -march=native
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ffast-math'
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-march=native'
    _lightfm_fast_no_openmp.c
    c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include\pyconfig.h(243): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include f
ile: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit
status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\
Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-gao0_4o3\\lightfm\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code
=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\hp\AppData\Lo
cal\Temp\pip-eybv98gb-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1
in C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-gao0_4o3\lightfm\
```

I have installed microsoft visual c++ 14 and even miniconda but still the same error. Please any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks in advance

Comment: compiling python packages on windows when installing is roulette. I usually go with downloading the windows pre-built wheels. unfortunately that doesn't seem to exist (yet)

Answer (score 2):

Try this option:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge lightfm
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install it via pip or via its Git-repository?

Their [documentation](http://lyst.github.io/lightfm/docs/home.html#pypi) states:

> Install from pypi using pip: `pip install lightfm`. Everything should
>   work out-of-the box on Linux, OSX using Homebrew Python, and Windows
>   using Miniconda.

Did you use the OS appropriate package manager? Are you sure it is supposed to work with python3.5, which you appear to be using?

Please, also note on [their git-page](https://github.com/lyst/lightfm) that only Linux OS seems to have a full pass, the other major OS's (macOS en Windows) have not.. which leads me to believe the pip-install might still be unstable. Maybe you could try the development-install tips? Or file an issue on Git.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have tried using pip install lightfm which is what gives that error and I have also tried the development install tips but still no luck and there is a similar issue in their Git repository

Comment: Well, you are clearly missing `basetsd.h`.. A Google search does seem to point towards it being a Visual Studio file, maybe you could try to reinstall Visual Studio, see if it helps.. If that doesn't help maybe you could try to compile the software yourself, since it's open source. Else.. I am guessing filing an issue on their Git would be your best bet.

Comment: Ah, no wait.. your error message also states it fails on a command that contains the phrase `import setuptools`. So maybe you could try `pip install setuptools` first! I've seen this solve similar looking errors before.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me at a direction I would try to reinstall visual studio and if it does not work then I would file an issue on their git

Comment: Ps: as you are using python3.5 your best bet would actually be `pip3 install setuptools` and afterwards `pip3 install lightfm`. On some systems/setups you could even do `pip35`

Comment: Ok I tried to install setuptools it says it already exists then i tried to `pip install record` when it started building wheels it failed with a similar microsoft c++ 14 error

Comment: Too bad.. sorry to not be able to be of more help.

Comment: I think I would try to reinstall the microsoft C++ 14 again

Comment: Yes.. or maybe lightfm doesn't play well with C++ 14 yet.. I just tried `pip3 install lightfm` on my macOS (using python3.4) and it completed without any problem.

Comment: Wish I had a Mac right now well I would have used a virtualbox but to start installing all this my application dependencies and all this packages

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you, on Windows OS. Try installing the package with conda, by running one of the following:

`conda install -c conda-forge lightfm`

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 lightfm`

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 lightfm`

The third command line worked for me.